# Java - read a .dot (graph) file from terminal

Tags: java, input, dot

I have to pass to my java program a .dot file and read its content. How can I do that? Could you post me the code?

I read several answers regarding input files but I didn't find the right answer, because most of them were about specifying the path inside the program instead of passing it from terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have no code because I don't know how to accomplish that. I hope that somebody could post me the code to do that.

Comment: Does this help? https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CD8QFjAEahUKEwiPnJC2wP3GAhWJ9HIKHd8NCsI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loria.fr%2F~szathmar%2Foff%2Fprojects%2Fjava%2FGraphVizAPI%2Fdownload%2FGraphViz.java&ei=H0q3Vc-QEonpywPfm6iQDA&usg=AFQjCNH3wCq6AsIY7n6UgPmA2AfBa-tbCw

Comment: @BretC Normally it would, but unfortunately this is an university project where I can't use already existing packages but the ones for input/output. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [graphstream](http://graphstream-project.org/).

AFAIK, it can read `.dot` files and visualize them. [Samples](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Reading-files-using-FileSource_1.0/).